# iOS CocoaPod warning - "Google has been deprecated" - when using pod 'Google/SignIn'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, deprecated, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am following this official Google doc:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

which states to use `pod 'Google/SignIn'`

However, I get the following warning:

`[!] Google has been deprecated`

On Google's documents, I don't see anything which states that it's deprecated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google's iOS pods got separated. You should use `GoogleSignIn`, which has the same functionality and Google still supports it.

You should simply remove the slash, like this:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Plus it seems like this doesn't install the Firebase stuff which I don't need anyway. I wonder if their docs are out of date or something. Will accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @PranoyC They are, in fact, out of date. I would recommend to check other sources as well, although it seems that the rest of it still holds today.